# AngularJS: need to show in a popup title "Expired"

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a clock in the UI where when I hover I see a date. When expired I should see only the word Expired but I see instead the date plus expired. Please check the screenshot:[clock hover expired](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGtSg.png) I shared.

I'm sharing with you the code doing that and I'm sure that I made a mistake there:

```
$scope.getBannerScheduledTitle = function(banner) {

        var today = new Date();
        var dd = today.getDate();
        var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
        var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

        var banner_from = null;
        var banner_to = null;

        if(banner.from){
            var pFromDate = new Date(banner.from);

            if($scope.countrycode == "US")
                banner_from = (pFromDate.getMonth()+1) + "/" + pFromDate.getDate() + "/" + pFromDate.getFullYear();
            else
                banner_from = pFromDate.getDate() + "/" + (pFromDate.getMonth()+1) + "/" + pFromDate.getFullYear();
        }
        if(banner.to){
            var pToDate = new Date(banner.to);

            if($scope.countrycode == "US")
                banner_to = (pToDate.getMonth()+1) + "/" + pToDate.getDate() + "/" + pToDate.getFullYear();
            else
                banner_to = pToDate.getDate() + "/" + (pToDate.getMonth()+1) + "/" + pToDate.getFullYear();
        }
        if(dd<10) {
            dd='0'+dd
        } 

        if(mm<10) {
            mm='0'+mm
        } 

        today = dd+'/'+mm+'/'+yyyy;

        var title = "";
        if (banner.from && banner.to == null)
            title += "from " + banner_from + " to " + " ... ";
        if (banner.to && banner.from == null)
            title += "from " + today + " to " + banner_to;
        if (banner.to && banner.from)
            title += "from " + banner_from + " to " + banner_to;
        if (banner.expired === true)
            title +=  "Expired";

        return title;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Mmmm I think you just need to change this:

```
 (...)  if (banner.expired === true)
            title +=  "Expired";

        return title;
```

To:

```
   if (banner.expired === true)
           title = "Expired";

        return title;
```

tell me.

Comment: when you do += you are making a concat of information, when you do = you are refilling that variable.
;)
You're welcome!

Comment: Thank you :) yeah that nice I just was too tired to see that hehe